# styling css by confdition from the backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend

dealing with reactjs, can we change css style with condition from the backend ?

to give an exemple, if the API returns true the background become blue, if returns false the background become green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, you can do like this:

```
<div className={`${true ? 'blue' : 'green'}`} />
```

Comment: While the answer is correct, it's best to explain it for newbies.